# org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

Tags: java, spring, templates, jdbc

i'm this following error when i submit for copying data here is the code..

```
public String deleteExistingRecordWeekWise(String monthOrWeek) throws ApplicationException {

    try {

        setMonthAndArea();

        String[] stringValues = selectedMonthAndYear.split("-");
        int year=Integer.parseInt(stringValues[0]);
        int month=Integer.parseInt(stringValues[1]);

        String timePrd = null;
        String wk = null;


        if(null==timePeriod || timePeriod.isEmpty()){
            timePeriod= new ArrayList <String>();
            timePeriod.add("2");
        }
        if(null==weekWise || weekWise.isEmpty()){
            weekWise= new ArrayList <String>();
            weekWise.add("1");
        }
        if(Integer.parseInt(timePeriod.get(0))==2){
            timePrd="W";
            if(null==weekWiseSelection){
                if(Integer.parseInt(weekWise.get(0))==1){
                    wk="W1";
                }else if(Integer.parseInt(weekWise.get(0))==2){
                    wk="W2";
                }else {
                    wk="W3";
                }
            }else{
                wk=weekWiseSelection;
            }
        }

        ReportsBO.deleteProjectStatusWeekWise(wk,month,year,selectedArea);

    } catch (ApplicationException ex) {
        addActionError(ex.getMessage());
        fetchFields();
        return ERROR;
    }

    if(null!=weekWiseSelection || !weekWiseSelection.equalsIgnoreCase("month")){
        addActionMessage("Existing records are deleted and copied data from previous month.");
    }else{
        addActionMessage("Existing records are deleted and copied data from previous bi weekly.");
    }
    return SUCCESS;
```

and DAO class..

public void deleteProjectStatusWeekWise(String week,int month,int year,String area) throws ApplicationException {
        int areaId=Integer.parseInt(area);

```
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    try {
        int projId = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(ProjectStatus.FETCH_PROJECT_STATUS_WEEKWISE,new Object[] {week,month,year,areaId});
        jdbcTemplate.update(ProjectStatus.DELETE_PROJECT_DET_STATUS_MONTH,new Object[] {projId});
        jdbcTemplate.update(ProjectStatus.DELETE_PROJECT_STATUS_WEEKWISE,new Object[] {week,month,year,areaId});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occurred in dashboard.performance.gmu.dao.ProjectStatusDAO.fetchProjectStatusTypeList(int)",e);
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to fetch project type list. Please contact System Administrator.");
    }
```

}

this error is coming can anyone help on this to resolve the issue.

```
}
```

Comment: What error is thrown? What's the expected behavior? Could you try to show us a minimal example?

Comment: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0 this following error it's throwing

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is probably coming from `jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(...);`. An [EmptyResultDataAccessException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/dao/EmptyResultDataAccessException.html) is thrown when a result was expected to have at least one row (or element) but zero rows (or elements) were actually returned.  Check to make sure the `projId` actually exists in the database.